# What does for(int i = 0; a[i]; i++) mean?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I have a `string a`.
What does the condition `a[i]` in the for loop `for(int i = 0; a[i]; i++)` mean?

Comment: uhm what? it is supposed to be a boolean expression or maybe 0 or 1?

Comment: This is not the right way to iterate through a string.

Comment: You should post a compilable example. Anyway, the middle part of the for expression is a boolean, so the compiler will try to convert whatever you write there to a bool. If the conversion can be made, it will compile. In your case, it will evaluate a[i]. Assuming (guessing) that it is a char, it will convert it to a bool. It will be false if a[i] is equal to 0, and true otherwise.

Comment: @DanielDaranas It's not always necessary to post a fully compilable example. I think the pose is quite clear and the closing requests rather harsh.

Comment: @Walter On a second thought, I agree with you. The specific question "what does a[i] mean?" can be answered with the information provided. Actually, if `a` is a string, `a[i]` (for a valid `i`) _is_ a char, so no guessing or assuming is required. Since he starts from 0, `a[i]` is guaranteed to be valid.

Comment: @DanielDaranas I don't think `a[i]` is simply a char if it is in a second part of a loop.

Comment: @duy.nguyen.se What you're talking about? if `a` is a string, then `a[i]` is a `char` (or perhaps a `const char&`). Doesn't matter whether it's in a loop or not.

Comment: @quokka If `a` is a string, `a[i]` (for a valid value of the integer index `i`) is a char. In a second part of a loop, that char will be implicitly converted to a bool, to become the value of the loop continuation condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case "for(int i = 0; a[i]; i++)", your loop keeps its execution until one of its elements are a null element. Always when you see this expression, it  is always the same meaning that is checking out whether element is or not null, in order to stop the loop.

However that loop has a undefined behavior, because if the index i will arrive at maximum array's size. It's likely you are going to receive a run-time error of that type:

Error for being out of range array size or you are trying to access a null space of memory.

I hope that my answer, it is suitable for your problem..

Comment: "*However that loop has a undefined behavior*" - in general, perhaps, but in this particular example, it is well-defined behavior in C++11 and later, because `a` is a `std::string`, and `std::string::operator[]` is defined in C++11 to return a reference to a null character when `i == a.size()`.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `i` is initialised to `0`, then incremented until `a[i]` is (or converts to) false, i.e. `a[i]==0`. Thus, `i` loops over all characters in the string until the first occurence of `\0`. For the usual null-terminated string, this is equivalent to

```
for(auto c:a)
```

Comment: @Ðаn Correct, but that was not the question. It's not that bad, though.

Comment: @Ðаn why not? Just curious, it may not be idiomatic but it works fine

Comment: These loops are not equivalent.  `for(auto c:a)` will loop through the entire string.  `for(int i = 0; a[i]; i++)` will loop until it finds the first null character which may not be the entire string.

Comment: @NathanOliver Okay, but that only makes a difference for other than null-terminated strings. I have amended my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

`for(int i = 0; a[i]; i++)` has the same meaning as `for(int i = 0; a[i] != 0; i++)`, which means "enter the loop until the element `a[i]` gets `0`; if `a` is a string, then this means "enter the loop until `a[i]` points to the string terminating character `\0`.

Note, however, that C++ offers other ways of iterating through the characters of a string, like, for example, `for (auto c : a) { cout << c << endl; }`

Answer (score -3):

It is searching chars of a string pointer array one by one. However, because it is defined as string in your code, compile time error occurs.

Comment: There's no compile error. It's perfectly valid code.